# Converting from react-router-dom to NextJS

Tags: next.js, react-router-dom

I'm not sure how I can replicate this in NextJS using their router api instead of react-router-dom.

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import auth from "../../services/authService";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ path, component: Component, render, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (!auth.getCurrentUser())
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: props.location }
              }}
              j
            />
          );
        return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

This is used like so:

```
 <ProtectedRoute path="/form/:id" component={Form} />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Next.js documents, you'd better use `Link` instead of `React-router-dom` or any other router.

Answer (score 0):

if think you could refactor your component to achieve the desired result:

(using nextjs v13 with page router, note that app router router.replace does not accept the same arguments)

(notes: I removed some parameters: "rest", "props" and changed the "Component"/"render" to children)

```js
import auth from "../../services/authService";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ path, children }) => {
  // This is an equivalent to react-router useNavigate()
  const router = useRouter();

  if (!auth.getCurrentUser()) {
    router.replace({ pathname: "/login", query: { from: props.location }});
    return null;
  }

  // user is auth, we render the component
  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```